# TypeORM When updating a specific column, save without affecting UpdateDateColumn

Tags: typeorm

I want to save without affecting UpdateDateColumn when updating view column.

This table is a post table and the view is a hit.

UpdateDateColumn is updated when adding the number of view Column.

I don't want the view column to affect UpdateDateColumn.

```
@Entity("post")
export default class Post extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  idx: number;

  // Skip
  
  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    default: 0
  })
  view: number;

  @Column("timestampz")
  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @Column("timestampz")
  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

Give me a solution please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but still a solution...

You can force update your date column with the value it has:

```
getRepository(Post).update(postId, {
  view: newViewValue,
  updated_at: () => '"updated_at"'
})
```

The SQL-query will look like:

```
UPDATE "post" SET "view" = $2, "updated_at" = "updated_at" WHERE "idx" = $1
```